# Subquery returns more than 1 row in SELECT part(Dlookup to MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

I am migrating a desktop application from MS Access VBA to Java Springboot application and I need to make a VBA query work in MySQL. The VBA query is insanely big so I present to you a smaller example to demonstrate my situation.
VBA query:

```sql
SELECT SELECT tbl_trade.id, 
   DLookUp("[price]","tbl_so_manifest","[so_id] = " 
   & tbl_trade.so_id & " AND [product_id] = " & tbl_po_manifest.product_id),
   // .... many more attributes....
FROM tbl_so_manifest as sm (((
   /// 15 nested INNER JOINS ....
   INNER JOIN tbl_trade AS t ON sm.so_id = t.so_id 
   INNER JOIN tbl_po_manifest AS pm ON sm.product_id = pm.product_id
   )));
```

MySQL conversion:

```sql
SELECT SELECT tbl_trade.id, 
   (SELECT sm.product_id 
   FROM tbl_so_manifest as sm 
      INNER JOIN tbl_trade AS t ON sm.so_id = t.so_id 
      INNER JOIN tbl_po_manifest AS pm ON sm.product_id = pm.product_id), 
   // ......
FROM tbl_so_manifest as sm (((
   /// 15 nested INNER JOINS ....
   INNER JOIN tbl_trade AS t ON sm.so_id = t.so_id 
   INNER JOIN tbl_po_manifest AS pm ON sm.product_id = pm.product_id
   )));
```

but it gives error

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row    0.844 sec

Suggestions needed on how to handle this.

Comment: At a very high level - the immediate solution would be for each of your sub queries to use the `LIMIT` clause  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp . Dlookup returns the first occurence of matched criteria, so you'd just mimic this same behavior by taking the first value returned in the subquery.

Comment: Are there more than one price for each unique `so_id` and `product_id` in *tbl_so_mainfest*? Also MySQL subquery does not retrieve *price* like MS Access' `DLookUp` and why `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @Parfait. No ach unique so_id and product_id in tbl_so_mainfest has only one price. I used inner join because I wasn't sure of what else. Any suggestions please.

Comment: @Mike. good observation that Dlookup returns only one row. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can force the sub query to only return one reocrd with a top 1

So this:

```
DLookUp("[price]","tbl_so_manifest","[so_id] = " 
& tbl_trade.so_id & " AND [product_id] = " & tbl_po_manifest.product_id)
```

Becomes:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM tbl_so_manifest 
         WHERE so_ID = tbl_trade.so_id AND product_id = sm.product_id
         ORDER BY PRICE, ID DESC) AS MyPrice
```

So you actually don't need a join but simply "pluck" out the value. To restrict the sub query  to ONE record, the TOP 1 and the order by "PK" will ensure that only one row is returned. If you leave out the  "id", then if two top prices are the same, then you get two rows. By adding the "ID" to  the order by, then you will only ever get one row, even if 5 prices are the same.

If other tables in context  have same column name, then of course add the table qualifier to the above (but, it wrote it  as is due for short hand).

So, as a general rule, you can replace dlookup() with an above type  of query.
I not all that familiar with MySQL, so you might not be able to use the table alias as above, but all in all, use a top 1 and order by with "ID (or PK) tossed in after price or whatever in those cases where more then one row could exist. In most cases, a dlookup() should not have multiple values (but dlookup() always only returns one value). So in most "translates" from dlookup() to a sub-query, the  top 1 should not be required.

And I can't think that a dlookup() needs a "join". Dlookup() always hits one table, and so should a conversion from dlookup() to a sub query. You want column to pluck, the table, and then the criteria).

If the dlookup() is a FK value, then a left join to the lookup table is easier, will not cause extra rows in the query, but either approach is fine. I find that a sub-query has less chance of "messing" with the main query number of rows returned.

So, a dlookup() to sub-query is a one to one conversion. No join should be required, and as noted in most cases a TOP one + the "id/pk" appended should not  be required in most cases.

Comment: I understood your point that I need to select the first row but you suggested that I need not use the join if I use "Select price FROM tbl_so_manifest as sm
 WHERE sm.so_id = tbl_trade.so_id AND sm.product_id = tbl_po_manifest.product_id ORDER BY PRICE, ID LIMIT 1;"  then it says unknown column tbl_trade.so_id in 'where clause'. This error was the reason I used the INNER JOIN

Comment: Do you need the joined table or JUST in that lookup? The dlookup() is a one to one conversion to a sub query. The other columns  in your  original post occur later on via the joins. If the joined values are ONLY required inside of the dlookup() and now the sub-query, then fine. Your original query as written joins in the additional columns WAY farther down. If you place the join inside of the subquery, then what  about the join that occurs later on? (you would be doing it two times). And dumping the later on join quite much means you are VERY much changing the meaning of the query.

Comment: All I am suggesting is that  you want to adopt a logical one to one conversion. That way you modify the query without really having to total change or know the  original logic. Its possible that the sub query can't use or pick up the columns from the join you have later on, but I would at least try and adopt a one to one logical flip from dlookup() to a subquery. If you have several dlookups() then you have to repeat the join over and over as opposed to the one join in the main query at the end. I not familiar with MySQL so I don't know if the later on join columns can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the `INNER JOIN`s of subquery as you do not do it in MS Access' `DLookUp` (which interestingly you do not use the specified aliases in its criteria logic). Remember `SELECT` (ironically being first listed clause) is usually the last in SQL's order of operations, so it can read external columns, `t.so_id` and `pm.product_id` within the subquery.

```sql
...
  (SELECT sm.`price`
   FROM tbl_so_manifest as sm 
   WHERE sm.so_id = t.so_id 
     AND sm.product_id = pm.product_id) AS sub_name 
...
```

More efficiently use subquery as a derived table (or CTE in MySQL 8) to be joined with all other tables. This avoids the row by row calculation and runs look up once to be joined to full resultset.

```sql
SELECT 
   sm.`price`,
   ...
FROM tbl_so_manifest as sm
/// 15 nested INNER JOINS ....
INNER JOIN tbl_trade AS t ON sm.so_id = t.so_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_po_manifest AS pm ON sm.product_id = pm.product_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `so_id`, `product_id`, `price`
    FROM tbl_so_manifest
   ) sm
 ON sm.so_id = t.so_id 
 AND sm.product_id = pm.product_id;
```

Note: MySQL does not require parentheses around multiple `JOIN`s (which hopefully my [MS suggestion](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) will one day fix in MS Access SQL).

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the sub query to only return one reocrd using LIMIT 1 key word. 
(SELECT Price FROM tbl_so_manifest 
         WHERE so_ID = tbl_trade.so_id AND product_id = sm.product_id
         ORDER BY PRICE, ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS MyPrice